# How do I show a labels list on a static page in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I'm new on Blogger and coding and stuff...
I recently bought a template and I want to create a static page "/p/categories.html" to show all my labels, since I have a lot of label and I don't want show them all on my mainpage or sidebar.

I looked up code for the label widget but it doesn't work, probably because my template was moderated.

Here is my code on the "label widget" part. Can anyone tell me what to do?

```
<b:widget id='Label3' locked='false' title='Ca Sĩ' type='Label' visible='true'>
            <b:widget-settings>
              <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'/>
              <b:widget-setting name='showType'>ALL</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>true</b:widget-setting>
            </b:widget-settings>
            <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
      <b:include name='widget-title'/>
      <b:include name='content'/>
    </b:includable>
            <b:includable id='cloud'>
      <ul>
        <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
          <li><a class='label-name' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a></li>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>
    </b:includable>
            <b:includable id='content'>
      <div class='widget-content'>
        <b:class expr:name='data:this.display + &quot;-label&quot;'/>
        <b:include cond='data:this.display == &quot;list&quot;' name='list'/>
        <b:include cond='data:this.display == &quot;cloud&quot;' name='cloud'/>
      </div>
    </b:includable>
            <b:includable id='list'>
      <ul>
        <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
          <li><a class='label-name' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/><b:if cond='data:this.showFreqNumbers'><span class='label-count'>(<data:label.count/>)</span></b:if></a></li>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>
    </b:includable>
          </b:widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute `cond` on label widget like the following

```
<b:widget cond='data:view.url == "yourPageUrl"' ...
```

Comment: Please show your attempts. yourPageUrl should be like this `https://BlogUrl/p/categories.html`

Comment: Yes it is. http://vietsubsongs.blogspot.com/p/categories.html

Comment: I evn tried: <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "http://vietsubsongs.blogspot.com/p/categories.html"'>  </b:if>

Comment: The URL should begin with `https://` or `http://` as in my example. It works for me.

Comment: The first line of your code should be `<b:widget cond='data:view.url == "https://vietsubsongs.blogspot.com/p/categories.html"' id='Label3' locked='false' title='Ca Sĩ' type='Label' visible='true'>`

Comment: I figured probably no widgets work in the static page, so I put the code in <header> </header> with cond='data:view.url == "https://vietsubsongs.blogspot.com/p/categories.html"' and it actually work, bit I think that d make my header heavier to load.